# 演算子 "||" の前後を入れ替える書き方について

Tags: ruby

特定の上限によって演算子`||`の前後を入れ替えたいので以下のように書いています。

```
def foo_or_bar
  return foo || bar if condition
  bar || foo
end
```

ただ`foo`と`bar`が入れ替わるだけという事を活かした
うまい書き方はないかと思い質問いたしました。

何かそのような記述方法はありますか？

Comment: eval を使う方法がありますが、`eval(sprintf(condition ? "%1$s||%2$s" : "%2$s||%1$s", "foo", "bar"))` 無理やり過ぎますね…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`||` は短絡評価機能があって、第1項で結果が確定する (この場合、第1項が真) と第2項を評価しない(副作用も発生しない)、という動作をしますよね。そこまで再現するのは難しそうです。
また、 `||` はメソッドではない (`true.methods.grep(/\|\|/) #=> []`) ので、リフレクションを活用する(`.inject(&:||)` 的なこと)も難しそうです。

形が非対称であるところをどうにかしたいのであれば、 `if` や三項演算子で書いたほうがいいかもしれません。

Comment: なるほど、ありがとうございます。現状のコードままで行こうと思います。